# How do I make my trigger send an exception after the executeUpdate() method instead of before?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make an event driven database and application interaction. Basically what I want is the database to tell the application that something has changed in the database, and I'll implement an action listener in my application.

I want the database to generate an exception after a 'student' has been inserted, but the exception is generated before the data for the new 'student' is actually inserted, so before the statement.executeUpdate(newStudent) method. Making the insertion unsuccessful. Here is my SQL code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Trigger logic here:
    -- Perform actions or operations when the trigger fires
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'New data added to student table';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

java code:

```
public void addStudent() {
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        int id = 3;
        String name = "Johnny";
        int age = 21;

        String newStudent = "INSERT INTO student (id, name, age) VALUES (" + id + ", '" + name + "', " + age + ")";

        statement.executeUpdate(newStudent);
        System.out.println(name + " inserted");

        statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
    }
}
```

Also are there any better ways to implement an event driven database-application communication model?